# Exception has been thrown by the target when starting VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel

I am trying to read an Excel 2003 XLS doc  and when I used the JET 4 Driver, there seemed to be an issue with reading merged cells: data is dropped.

So, I tried the ACE driver for 2007:

XLS http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

And it read the XLS just fine but now I am having issues with VS 2010

[image]

When I uninstalled this, my VS2010, seem to work again. When I reinstall it, I get the error again the next time I reboot.

However, it seems unlikely to me that the error is caused by this driver an I am wondering if it is really j ust a cooincidence and that the real issue is something else.

Are the two related? How do I resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

I am researching this very issue and all signs point to installing/re-applying SP1 for VS2010.